# Nativescript-Angular - tns preview -> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, tns

My emulator with tns run Android `--env.aot` gives me a nice app without errors.

Tns preview or tns preview `--env.aot` gives me this:
[image]

I think it has something to do with versions or just missing some things but I can't get it right.

Even if I start a new project without any code the same error appears.

Comment: Hey there, this issue should be fixed. Could you give it another try?

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer. It's fixed but i got myself another error..  

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Error: Could not find module '@nativescript/angular'.

Not sure what this is about.. Any suggestions maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently an issue with Nativescript playground. I analysed the endpoint, and can see that's it's not receiving the expected data, hence the failure.

Even the web version of the playground isn't working correctly. Send them a message, or open an issue on their GitHub. The more of us that flag the issue, they'll acknowledge it, and not just put it down to user error.

Comment: Thank you for answering! 

I think you're right found a github issue : https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/5356

It looks like it's solved so im gonna try it later today. 

Kind regards,
R